# MSI H81M E33 Mobo - Now won't boot

Tags: windows-7, boot, ssd, motherboard, bsod

Just bought myself a new bare bones system with the MSI H81M E33 Mobo.

Droppped my current SSD into the system, and off it went happy as larry.

Installed all MOBO drivers and all running well, but after about 2 hours rebooted itself for no reason into the UEFI shell (A new concept to me that confused the hell out of me!).

I got it back into Windows 7 (I run 64bit Pro) and same thing happened. Sensed there may be a driver issue I went for a fresh Windows install on a freshly formatted SATA HDD. That went well, with Windows installed, Norton and then the MOBO drivers. Then the system, gave me BSOD, rebooted, and then  for three times as I saw the swirling Windows colours as Windows loads, it hit BSOD again for a split second. It did that twice. Now It doesn't do a thing, and after powering off I can't even get it into the BIOS.

I power on, I hear my disc spinning, the monitor keybopard and mouse all light up, but nothing appears on the screen, no beeps either. Disconnected the SSD, keyboard and mouse and still the same. Monitor light up, but nothing happens.

What are people's views on the problem? Do I have a lemon of a Mobo?

Comment: Have you tried removing the CMOS battery?  After (if) you get it back up don't install the driver in question its not even required.

Comment: @Ramhound - Yes, I have tried removing the battery for 15 mins or so. Same Problem. You say "Don't install the driver in question" Which driver might that be then? I've installed all those on the MOBO CD, that MSI believe I need (There is an "Install Everything" option, which I ran.)

Answer (score -2):

I had the same problem with my motherboard. You need to flash the MB. There is some SATA problems with the MB. Try to disconnect the HDD *power or sata*. Flash the bios. Then in the BIOS save & exit before you hit enter. Connect the hdd again and then hit enter & it should start normally again :)

Comment: Please use complete sentences and whole words. I can barely understand your answer.